# Apache SparkUI on local mode

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I'm new to Apache Spark. Currently using in on IntelliJ IDEA 14, maven project method. I'm unable to access the Spark UI after my program stops because of

```
 15/10/22 23:28:27 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.88:4041
```

SparkUI stops too fast for me to review what my program does. Is there any way to review the SparkUI for the particular program after it's stopped? Or can I find some kind of log that is created after running the program?

After setting "spark.eventLog.enabled" to true and "spark.eventLog.dir" to a local folder, I was able to produce Unix executable files(local-1445955378567). However, the details of the log is not what I expected. How do I add SparkListener??

[Output of unix executable"local-1445955378567"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEEXR.jpg)

Comment: For me running in Jupyter environment I had to go to : http://host.docker.internal:4040/jobs/

Spark session is already active when you run the cells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either keep the ui alive (by keeping your context alive) or start a history server since the ui is tied to the context. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html